# Problem while trying to reinstall devstack

Tags: rabbitmq, devstack

I once installed openstack using devstack on my Ubuntu 22.04, and I removed it to free up storage. Now when I attempt to re-install it, using the link: https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack and the document for devstack: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/index.html
I encounter this problem below:

```
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.9.13-1ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xeu rabbitmq-server.service" for details.

invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-02-06 16:22:57 +07; 3ms ago
Process: 193900 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 193900 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Status: "Standing by"
    CPU: 580ms
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
installed rabbitmq-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
```

And when I run journalctl -xe:

```
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191671]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/grep -q ^\\[Journal\\] /etc/systemd/journald.conf     
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191671]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191671]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191677]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/sed -ne '/^\\[Journal\\]/,/^\\[.*\\]/ { /^RateLimitBurst[ \\t]*=/ p; }' /etc/systemd/jo>
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191677]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191677]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191681]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/sed -i -e '/^\\[Journal\\]/,/^\\[.*\\]/ s#01^\\(RateLimitBurst[ \\t]*=[ \\t]*\\).*$#01\>
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191681]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191681]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191688]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl restart systemd-journald
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191688]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:21:23 dothai sudo[191688]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192377]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/grep -q ^\\[Manager\\] /etc/systemd/system.conf
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192377]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192377]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192383]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/sed -ne '/^\\[Manager\\]/,/^\\[.*\\]/ { /^DefaultLimitNOFILE[ \\t]*=/ p; }' /etc/system>
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192383]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192383]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192387]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/sed -i -e '/^\\[Manager\\]/,/^\\[.*\\]/ s#01^\\(DefaultLimitNOFILE[ \\t]*=[ \\t]*\\).*$>
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192387]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192387]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192398]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl daemon-reload
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192398]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192398]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192563]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; ENV=DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get --optio>
Feb 06 16:21:30 dothai sudo[192563]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:22:11 dothai sudo[192563]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:22:12 dothai sudo[193234]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; ENV=http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get update
Feb 06 16:22:12 dothai sudo[193234]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:22:14 dothai sudo[193234]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:22:14 dothai sudo[193813]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; ENV=DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get --optio>
Feb 06 16:22:14 dothai sudo[193813]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[193813]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194198]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ovs-vsctl list-br
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194198]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194198]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194203]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ovs-vsctl show
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194203]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194203]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194207]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables --line-numbers -L -nv -t filter
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194207]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194207]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194211]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables --line-numbers -L -nv -t nat
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194211]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194211]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194215]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables --line-numbers -L -nv -t mangle
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194215]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194215]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194219]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/ebtables -t filter -L
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194219]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194219]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194223]:    stack : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/stack/devstack ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/ebtables -t nat -L
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194223]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=1001)
Feb 06 16:22:58 dothai sudo[194223]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I guess this is the problem related to rabbitmq installation, and I tried to remove then install it manually. I also searched the solution, none of them work to me.
I am so confused right now, and I am really grateful if anybody helps me with it. Thank you very much.